# How to Index Pandas Dataframe with a List of Slices

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames, `ret` and `bins`. I would like to take index values from `bins`, create a range for every row in `bins` and then use that list of ranges to select the data from `ret`. Somehow this works when I pass an index of slices (manually typed in), but doesn't work when I pass in a list saved in the variable `a`

```
ret = pd.DataFrame({'px': [.1, -.15, .30, -.20, .05]})
bins = pd.DataFrame({'t1': [3,4]}, index=[1,2])
a = []
for i, b in bins.iterrows():
    a.append(slice(i, b.t1))

print('a',a)
print('np.r_[a]',np.r_[a])
print('np.r[slice',np.r_[slice(1, 3, None) , slice(1, 4, None)])
print(ret.iloc[np.r_[slice(1, 3, None) , slice(1, 4, None)]]) # this WORKS
print(ret.iloc[a] #this DOES NOT WORK)
```

here is the output:

```
a [slice(1, 3, None), slice(2, 4, None)]
np.r_[a] [slice(1, 3, None) slice(2, 4, None)]
np.r[slice [1 2 1 2 3]
     px
1 -0.15
2  0.30
1 -0.15
2  0.30
3 -0.20
...
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'
```

Comment: What's your expected output for this sample data? Also, you are aware that python is `0` index, i.e. arrays start with index `0`?

Comment: The expected outcome is achieved with code ret.iloc[np.r_[slice(1, 3, None) , slice(1, 4, None)] which prints out  1 -0.15  2  0.30  1 -0.15 2  0.30 3 -0.20 (see above it does work). I'm aware of the index starting from 0, this is just for demonstration). My problem is that ret.iloc[a] doesn't work even though it's seemingly the same as the code that works.

Comment: `r_` produces a 1d array of index values.  `a` is a list slice objects.  Those are not the same!  `a` is not in the list of allowable inputs to `iloc`.

Comment: How do I make them the same? sending np.r_[a] into the .iloc function was my first guess and creates the same error.

Comment: Look at `np.r_[a]` - it does not expand `a` into that array.

Comment: `np.hstack([np.arange(1,3), np.arange(1,4)]) `  replicates the `np.r_` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here! Problem was slice() is too cumbersome to use. Easier to just flatten the lists of arrays. If anyone has any suggestions please post here!

```
ret = pd.DataFrame({'px': [.1, -.15, .30, -.20, .05]})
bins = pd.DataFrame({'t1': [3,4]}, index=[1,2])
a = [ret[i:b.t1].index for i, b in bins.iterrows()]
out = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
print(ret.loc[out])
>>>     px
>>>1 -0.15
>>>2  0.30
>>>2  0.30
>>>3 -0.20
```